# C/C++ Bug gdb atof(argv[1]) need to change to idb to work

Tags: c++

I just dont get it why this C++ program don't want to work?
Help!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // convert the text argv[1] to double using atof:
    double r = atof(argv[1]);
    double s = sin(r);
    cout << "Hello, World! sin(" << r << ")=" << s << endl;
    // success
    return 0;
}
```

Report:

```
"/usr/bin/gmake" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
gmake[1]: Entering directory /home/aleksandar/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_2'
"/usr/bin/gmake" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/GNU_Compiler_Collection-Linux-x86/cppapplication_2
gmake[2]: Entering directory /home/aleksandar/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_2
mkdir -p build/Debug/GNU_Compiler_Collection-Linux-x86
rm -f build/Debug/GNU_Compiler_Collection-Linux-x86/main.o.d
g++ -c -g -MMD -MP -MF build/Debug/GNU_Compiler_Collection-Linux-x86/main.o.d -o build/Debug/GNU_Compiler_Collection-Linux-x86/main.o main.cpp
mkdir -p dist/Debug/GNU_Compiler_Collection-Linux-x86
g++ -o dist/Debug/GNU_Compiler_Collection-Linux-x86/cppapplication_2 build/Debug/GNU_Compiler_Collection-Linux-x86/main.o
gmake[2]: Leaving directory `/home/aleksandar/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_2'
gmake[1]: Leaving directory `/home/aleksandar/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_2'

BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 613ms)

RUN FAILED (exit value 1, total time: 78ms)
```

`/usr/local/netbeans-7.2.1/ide/bin/nativeexecution/dorun.sh: line 33: 7673 Segmentation fault sh "${SHFILE}"`
`Press [Enter] to close the terminal ...`

Update:

I've contacted professor on that University and solution he told me is:
 
If I wanna run the code in a unix/linux environment, I need after compiling and linking with say:
`c++ -o test.x test.cpp`
 
Then run the code as:
 
`./test.x 0.4` 
And now it works.
The output is
`Hello, World! sin(0.4)=0.389418` 
But do anyone know way to enter 0.4 in console in compiler and not like this??

Comment: When my C++ programs don't want to work, I pull out my whip. Anyway, I'm guessing `argv[1]` doesn't exist.

Comment: Are you sure your program is the one that is crashing as you have only shared the output from your build tool.  Also, your main() doesn't check to see if it received enough arguments to have a valid argv[1]. More information would help.

Answer (score 2):

`argv[1]` is only valid if `argc >= 2`.  You should check for that in your code.

And `argc` is only greater than `1` when you run the program with command-line arguments.

Answer (score 2):

This is crashing because you aren't necessarily sending a command-line argument to the program.  argv[0] is always the name of the executable you're running, but argv[1] is not guaranteed to exist or to be allowed to be dereferenced.

If you're interested in getting input from the user, you should use std::cin located in the header iostream.  You can include it with the following code at the top of your program

```
#include <iostream>
```

and to read a floating-point value from the user, you could do something like the following (assuming using namespace std;):

```
float var;
cout << "Enter a number: ";
cin >> var;
```

and after that code is executed, var will contain the floating-point value the user input.

Comment: I've contacted professor on that University and solution he told me is:<br/>
"If you run the code in a unix/linux environment, after compiling and linking with say

`c++  -o  test.x test.cpp`

You run the code as
`./test.x 0.4`"
But I still dont get why it need to be like that??

Answer (score 1):

You didn't provide any command-line arguments so `argv[1]` causes the segmentation fault.

Answer (score -1):

!!!SOLVED!!!

The probem was: bug in gdb I needed to change to intel64/idb to work!!!

I've tried everything different compilers and programs to run them(Netbeans,
Eclipse, Qt Creator.....)

When I changed: gdb->idb

IT WORKED!!!

bug is reported:
http://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=15257

Comment: From the information you've provided, this looks like a problem in your project settings, not in `gdb`.  Did you set the "command-line arguments" of the project in netbeans?